# Browser clear cache after changes

Tags: javascript, html, cache-manifest

So I have a website which is basically done with javascript and html. Using .NET for the backend. The thing is, I the user see the changes every time updates are done to the HTML, css, and js files.
I know I can add versions to the script tags, but that would require going to each and every file to change the version in the tag. 
I tried creating a cache manifest file, and update the version everytime I do changes, but it doesnt seem to work well.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2016-02-24 v1.0.1
```

I need the user to access the pages with the new changes from the first time the user access the pages after doing the changes.